# Discriminant of an elliptic curve over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

If we have an elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_p$ of the form:
$$
y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \ ,
$$
$a, b$ belonging to $\Bbb F_p$,
the discriminant is defined as:
$$
D = -16(4a^3 + 27b^2)\ .
$$
My question is: the calculation of $D$ should be done in $\Bbb F_p$? That is, is $D$ in $\Bbb F_p$? If not, in which ring should calculations be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $a,b\in \Bbb{F}_p$, so does $D = -16(4a^3 + 27b^2)$. It is better to normalize the discriminant (dividing by $a^3$) obtaining something equivalent to the $j$-invariant, which depends solely on the (isomorphism class of the) curve and not on the chosen parametrization/model.

Comment: Thank you José Carlos. Thank you reuns.